# Como puedo solucionar el error en el uso de typeof de awk

Tags: bash, awk

Estoy comenzando a usar awk y me da un error al usar typeof.

```
awk -F\; 'NR==1{print $1}NR==2{print typeof($1)}' fichero.csv
```

obtengo el error

```
awk: line 2: function typeof never defined
```

¿debo instalar previamente algo?

Me gustaría poder leer el primer campo de un csv donde vienen separado por ; y mostrar el tipo de dato que contiene. (char, int....)

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontré que me faltaba instalar gawk.

con:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

y ya me funciona correctamente!

Comment: sí, [`typeof()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Type-Functions.html) es propio de GNU Awk, no está en el Awk "raso".